# Backend - Product Detail Page Load Images tab with ajax

Tags: product, adminhtml, product-images

I have some products with 200+ images and the product detail pages become very slow ( depending on the number of images can crash my browser too), probably because of the big amount of html and some js )

I would like to load the `images` tab with ajax, in this way the problem should be reduces ( any other suggestion is welcome )

How can I accomplish this ?

What I can see it that the tab is loaded by `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs::_prepareLayout()`

So I have rewriten this block and modified the `_prepareLayout()` method so that the tab is not loaded at the first but is set to be ajax:

```
              if ($group->getAttributeGroupName() == 'Images') {
                    $this->addTab('group_' . $group->getId(), array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
                        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/images', array('_current' => true)),
                        'class' => 'ajax',
                    ));
                } else {
                    $this->addTab('group_' . $group->getId(), array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
                        'content' => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                            'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                            ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                            ->toHtml()),
                    ));
                }
```

Then I rewrited the controller and created this action

```
public function imagesAction()
    {
        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $setId = $product->getAttributeSetId();

        $group = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection')
            ->setAttributeSetFilter($setId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name', 'Images')
            ->setSortOrder()
            ->getFirstItem();

        $attributes = $product->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);

        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('burnout_productpart/adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tabs_images',
            'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
            ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
            ->toHtml();
        Mage::getSingleton('core/translate_inline')->processResponseBody($html);

        echo $html;
    }
```

The content loads but I have some js script errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: media_gallery_contentJsObject is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs::_prepareLayout`. In there take a look to how this is done for categories.

Then you can apply the same for the image attribute. Instead doing something like:

```
$this->addTab('group_'.$group->getId(), array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($group->getAttributeGroupName()),
    'content' => $this->_translateHtml($this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                    'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                        ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                        ->toHtml()),
            ));
```

inside the loop, you can then add the tab via ajax (like for categories) by adding a custom controller who prints the image block:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->getAttributeTabBlock(),
                    'adminhtml.catalog.product.edit.tab.attributes')->setGroup($group)
                        ->setGroupAttributes($attributes)
                        ->toHtml()
```

Comment: check update ... I managed that but I still have some js errors

Comment: Try to define that variable when showing the product. I'm pretty sure the content will be populated after you load by ajax the block.